# MySql query multiple large tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 10 tables with approximately 20 million rows in each. All the tables have same structure but different data i.e. Name, MobileNumber, Address. All the tables has indexes. For any record I have to search all the tables. I've create a view with command:

```
Create view myview as 
Select * from table1 Union
Select * from table2 Union
...
Select * from table10
```

but when I tried to query the view like

```
Select * from myview WHERE MobileNumber = '1111111111'
```

the server did not respond for hours. So how to query all the tables efficiently and elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will never be able to optimize a query using `union`, because `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

The query will be faster using `union all`.  That said, I'm not sure if MySQL will be able to use the indexes on the underlying tables, even with `union all`.  However, it will not be attempting to remove duplicates which will be a big performance improvement.

Comment: even with `union all` if MySql create a temp table without index, it will be of no use because search through 200 million rows without Index isn't working at all.

Comment: @Khalil . . . But it won't be removing duplicates which is even more expensive than creating a temporary table.

Comment: I've tried `union all` and as I said it is also taking long time.